# Texture coordinate UV - black?

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

I face a weird behavior which I cannot understand, therefore any help would be appreciated.
For one of my objects, the "texture coordinates/UV" value is all black which seems to indicate that it doesn't work.
For the other ones everything is fine.

I've tried to unwrap again, either classic unwrap or smart or cube, without success. I've also tried to recompute normals or flip them but it doesn't change anything.

What can possibly go wrong here?

[image: Texture coordinate issue]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Is it intentional that there are several UVs overlapping each other? It would also be interesting to see the complete shader nodes setup and not just the _Texture Coordinate_ node...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The overlap is the result of the default cube projection unwrap. 
And actually, the shader node is just the texture coordinate node sent to the output, that's why I only showed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution though not understanding why it worked. I copied the mesh from the "black/non functional" object into one of the "colored/ok" objects which seemed to recreate the UV coordinates. Then I split the mesh by "selection" and the new object kept the UV coordinates.

I still don't understand what was the issue and why that operation fixed it.